# What's Ruby's equivalent to Python's setDefault()?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand Python has a `setDefault()` function that allows you to set the value for missing values.  However, I'm curious how this would port over to Ruby.

Specifically an example like this:

```
animals = Animal.objects

animal_names = {}

for animal in animals:
    a = animal_names.setdefault(animal.name, [])
    a.append({'color': animal.color, 'size': animal.size})
```

I think I could use this when programming Ruby but need to fully grasp the concept. I think an this example would make it clear for me.

Comment: For the non Python readers - what does this code do?

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate, but the answer there was wrong as well.  I added a more detailed example to the older post.  I also posted a simpler example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby has the hash.fetch method, you can use it for the same way to gracefully handle missing keys, the difference is it doesn't then store those values:

```
h = {}
value = h.fetch(:some_key, [])  
# value is now []
```

Another common way we accomplish what you are doing in Ruby is this:

```
h[:some_key] ||= []
```

or I guess you can even do this if you wanted to assign that to a value:

```
value = h[:some_key] ||= []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = Hash.new
h.default = "123"
puts h[any_key] //Prints 123
```

Comment: default doesn't do exactly the same thing.  Default will now assign that value to any missing key.  In Python it will only assign it to a specific key.  You can still do it by passing a proc to default, but I think that is going overboard.